# probability densitiy function of $-X$

Tags: probability, measure-theory

given a random variable $X$ with density $f_X(x)$. what is the density of $-X$? it's

$$f_{-X}(x)=f_X(-x),$$

isn't it? is that obvious? is there a descriptive explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have for any Borel set $A \subseteq \mathbf R$, that 
\begin{align*}
  \def\P{\mathbf P}\P[-X \in A] &= \P[X \in -A]\\
      &= \int_{-A} f_X(x)\, dx\\
      &= \int_A f_X(-x)\, dx
\end{align*}
So, the density of $-X$ is, as you write, $x \mapsto f_X(-x)$.

Answer (score 2):

If $X$ has a PDF then CDF $F_X$ is continuous, so that:

$F_{-X}(x)=P(-X\leq x)=P(X\geq-x)=1-F_X(-x)$

Then (if possible) differentiate both sides to find:

$f_{-X}(x)=f_X(x)$

This is not a complete proof since it might be that $F_X$ cannot be differentiated everywhere, but it affirms for a big deal that it is indeed obvious that $f_{-X}(x)=f_X(-x)$.

---

edit: I see now that @martini gave you a complete proof.